# How to give name to an index, associated with constraint in H2?

Tags: sql, h2, database-indexes

I am creating table with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE ELEM
(
  ID INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  TYP_ID INTEGER,
  SPELL VARCHAR(50),
  CONSTRAINT ELEM_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT ELEM_SK UNIQUE (ID, TYP_ID),
  CONSTRAINT ELEM_TYP_FK FOREIGN KEY (TYP_ID) REFERENCES TYP (ID)

);
```

in result I get indices with the names of `PRIMARY_KEY_2`, `ELEM_TYP_FK_INDEX_2` and `CONSTRAINT_INDEX_2`. Can I control these names in `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.